# Condition for Cloudformation Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudformation

So the thing is:

I have this resource creation set for AWS Cloudformation using ElasticBeanstalk, which creates additional internal_loadbalancer:

```
Resources:
IntLB: 
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
        ConnectionDrainingPolicy: 
            Enabled: true 
            Timeout: 20
        CrossZone: true
        HealthCheck:
            HealthyThreshold: 3
            Interval: 10
            Target: "TCP"
            Timeout: 5
            UnhealthyThreshold: 5
        Listeners: 
            - InstancePort: 443
              LoadBalancerPort: 443
              Protocol: HTTPS
              SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:
              InstanceProtocol: HTTP
        Scheme: internal
        SecurityGroups: 
            - { "Ref" : "AWSEBLoadBalancerSecurityGroup" }
        Subnets:
            - "subnet-1"
            - "subnet-2"
            - "subnet-3"
            - "subnet-4"
            - "subnet-5"
            - "subnet-6"

AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties: 
        LoadBalancerNames:
            - { "Ref" : "AWSEBLoadBalancer" }
            - { "Ref" : "IntLB" }
```

What I would like to do is write a condition that if environment_ID = XYZ then apply the creation of the resource and if not ignore it.

I was looking around for AWS documentation and forums but I'm not sure what would be the correct approach.

Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What if you create a [condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) and apply this to your resource?

```
Conditions: 
     CreateInternalELB: !Equals [ !Ref AWSEBEnvironmentId, XYZ ]
Resources:
    IntLB: 
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
        Condition: CreateInternalELB
        Properties:
            [...]
```

Change `XYZ` to your environment id.

I just wrote this on my phone, so please excuse any typos. Not sure either if you can include conditions like this in the EB structure.